# How a struct is taking an empty array and later how an address is going to be put there?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js, remix

As far I know, `new address[](number)` creates an fixed sized array of that number initialized with zero. But how in this line `Room memory room = Room(new address[](0), 0, 0);` **Room** struct is taking an empty array and later how an address is going to be put there?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract StructArrayInit {
  
  event OnCreateRoom(address indexed _from, uint256 _value);
  
  struct Room {
    address[] players;       
    uint256 whosTurnId;
    uint256 roomState;
  }  
  
  Room[] public rooms;

  function createRoom() public {
      Room memory room = Room(new address[](0), 0, 0);
      rooms.push(room);
      rooms[rooms.length-1].players.push(msg.sender);

      OnCreateRoom(msg.sender, 0);
  }
  function getRoomPlayers(uint i) public view returns (address[]){
      return rooms[i].players;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this statement:

```
Room memory room = Room(new address[](0), 0, 0);
rooms.push(room);
```

In the first line, he declared a Room struct variable with the following value: 0,0 and 0.
This means that `players`, `whosTurnId`, `roomState` struct variable have zero values.

With the second line, he pushed inside `rooms` array, `Room` struct variable created previously.
With this statement:

```
rooms[rooms.length-1].players.push(msg.sender);
```

he took the last element of array (what he has entered) then push inside `players` array inside `Room` struct the `msg.sender` value.
If you want to insert more address inside `players` array, you can use this statement:

```
rooms[rooms.length-1].players.push([address]);
```